# Can autotools be configured to do a rolling install/uninstall?

Tags: autotools

Let me be clear  what I mean by rolling install.

let us assume I am working on a project where I am installing the lib libmylib.so into /usr/lib.

The process I use to do this is simply type "make install".

Now let us assume that /usr/lib already contains /usr/lib/libmylib.so
and /usr/lib/libmylib.so.1 .

I want autotools to generate a makefile that does a

```
mv /usr/lib/libmylib.so.1 /usr/lib/libmylib.so.2
mv /usr/lib/libmylib.so  /usr/lib/libmylib.so.1
install libmylib.so into /usr/lib
```

I would also like, for some fixed number N to simply delete /usr/lib/libmylib.so.N instead of moving it.

I would also like a make target uninstall so that when I do "make unstall". The system is restored as well as it can be to befoire I installed it.

Comment: You do realize that the numbers on shared libraries have a meaning for your system, right? You can't just tack on random numbers to .so files and expect things to continue working.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an [`install-exec-local`](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Extending-Installation) and `install-data-local` rule in `Makefile.am`, for (example) `libmylib.so` and `mylib.h` respectively.

automake supports an [`uninstall-local`](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Install-Rules-for-the-User) rule. The other prefix is `-hook`, which runs *after* the corresponding rule.

Your scheme shouldn't be used for any released software, obviously. It breaks the expected behaviour of an autotools package, especially with a hard coding of the `/usr` prefix. You could use 'proper' [libtool versioning](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Libtool-versioning.html), which typically installs a `libmylib.la` metadata file as well.